# sys.argv[0] returns nothing and sys.arg[1] returns IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: tiff

I am very new to python and I encounter a problem when trying to convert tiff file to DAX file using a code from https://github.com/ZhuangLab/storm-analysis/blob/71ae493cbd17ddb97938d0ae2032d97a0eaa76b2/storm_analysis/sa_utilities/tiffs_to_dax.py

When running the this line: **dax_file = datawriter.DaxWriter(sys.argv[1])**,
it returns **IndexError: list index out of range**

I also checked sys.argv[0], and it returns nothing.

I am not sure what happens.

Does anyone know why it returned IndexError and it returned nothing when I tried sys.arg[0]?

Comment: Are you passing the two parameters it is expecting? `"usage: <dax> <tiff dir>"`

Comment: Sry i dont quite understand. basically i just run everything just as what the code from github wrote

Comment: https://opensourceoptions.com/how-to-pass-arguments-to-a-python-script-from-the-command-line/

Comment: @Zi Mian Hong – 
Instead of writing _basically i just run everything just as what the code from github wrote_ you should better write exactly how you ran the program in question.